# Stripping '�' from a string in python

Tags: python, regex, csv, amazon-redshift, bonobo-etl

I'm currently in the process of a large scale data migration, from multiple SQL Server databases to AWS Redshift. I'm using python + bonobos-etl for this task, and am pretty pleased with it so far. However, when migrating one specific table I've been running into an issue where there is a specific character cannot be transferred into Redshift. The Redshift error is as follows:

`Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x20 found at location 226`

As I understand it (though I could be wrong), this is the ASCII encoding for an EOL character.

Even if I delete the row in question, this error can be found occasionally throughout the millions of rows that I am importing, so I'd like to resolve this issue during the data extraction.

The character in question appears in my .csvs as: 
`�`

When I view it in the SQL Server Manager, is doesn't appear at all.

Here is my data cleansing function (admittedly a bit of a mess):

```
def transform(row, **kwargs):
    """Placeholder, change, rename, remove... """
    global commitCounter
    print(commitCounter)
    commitCounter += 1

    for myDict in row:

        for k,v in myDict.items():

            myDict[str(k)] = re.sub(' +', ' ', str(v)).strip()

            if myDict[str(k)] == "None":
                myDict[str(k)] = None

            try: myDict[str(k)] = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', myDict[str(k)]).replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "").replace("|", "")
            except: pass

            try: 
                myDict[str(k)] = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', myDict[str(k)])
            except: pass

            try:
                datetime.datetime.strptime(myDict[str(k)],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                myDict[str(k)] = myDict[str(k)].rpartition('.')[0]
            except: pass

        yield myDict
```

I was under the impression that this line in the code specifically would deal with the issue:

```
myDict[str(k)] = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', myDict[str(k)])
```

But it clearly is not. I am having trouble playing with the regex to fix the issue as I cannot copy/paste the character into the python shell nor on a regex testing service. Is there a quick and easy way I can check for my troublesome character? Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered fixing your database and/or Python encoding such that this character renders properly?

Comment: 0x20 is a space char. Check your data. Around “location 226”. Maybe your input is not quoted?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the advice. 
@TimBiegeleisen unfortunately changing the db encoding is out of the question. The dbs contain multiple decades of data, and I don't quite have permission to do such a thing. As far as changing the python encoding goes, I'd honestly rather just strip it as I do not see it adding any value to the data.

Comment: @randomir When I check the source db itself (via SQL Server Manager), no such character appears. In the .csv that is generated, the character appears as "�." Could you elaborate on how I could check if the input is quoted or not?

Comment: � indicates decoding with the wrong character encoding. If � is not in the source database, then your ETL is the problem.  It needs to solved with knowledge of the correct character encoding. (It is possible, though, that your predecessors made that an unattainable goal.)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/05/20/stripping-control-characters-in-python.html#)

Comment: Have you tries ACCEPTINVCHARS in the copy command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I figured out my issue. Though AWS Redshift was reporting the issue as `Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x20 found at location 226`, after converting the string to a byte string I found that the actual value of the misencoded string was: `x00`. Now it makes sense why `myDict[str(k)] = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', myDict[str(k)])` wouldn't properly filter out the character, as `\x00` is within the acceptable range. I instead added another try/except block, where I now replace `\x00` with an empty string, like so: `myDict[str(k)] = re.sub('\x00', '', myDict[str(k)])`

My .csvs are now devoid of the replacement character, so I believe the issue is resolved. It's odd that AWS reported the character as `0x20` when it was in reality `x00` but I'm unsure if thats a bug on their end or if I'm misunderstanding character encoding. Thank you all who commented with suggestions, as I was only able to figure it out through your guidance. I know its a bit anticlimactic for me to answer my own question, so if this goes against StackOverflow guidelines feel free to close this question. Thanks.